# Ensure Android app runs in a single process

Tags: java, android, sqlite, firebase, multiprocessing

We've recently started running into crashes in our Android app due to the app being open in multiple processes. Several different errors point towards that. For instance this error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to gain
>   exclusive lock to Firebase Database's offline persistence. This
>   generally means you are using Firebase Database from multiple
>   processes in your app. Keep in mind that multi-process Android apps
>   execute the code in your Application class in all processes, so you
>   may need to avoid initializing FirebaseDatabase in your Application
>   class. If you are intentionally using Firebase Database from multiple
>   processes, you can only enable offline persistence (i.e. call
>   setPersistenceEnabled(true)) in one of them.

We are also seeing similar errors from SQLite and H2. This is a new issue and we have not explicitly allowed multiple processes to run. Nothing in our AndroidManifest.xml specifies a custom android:process attribute.

I suspect that some third party library is causing this. How do I identify the root cause of the multiple processes and how do I prevent it?

Another of our apps is connecting to this app via a ContentProvider. At first I thought that it having `android:multiprocess="true"` was the culprit but changing it to "false" did not help. I still suspect that the other app is somehow triggering the creation of a new process. This is how to the ContentProvider is defined:

```
  <provider
        android:name=".DegooContentProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.DegooContentProvider"
        android:exported="true"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:multiprocess="false">
    </provider>
```

Comment: Examine your merged manifest in Android Studio to see the entire manifest and all the components that may be defining another process.

Comment: "Nothing in our AndroidManifest.xml specifies a custom android:process attribute.". Is there any other way to define a custom process?

Comment: I'm not saying there's anything in *your* manifest.  What I'm saying is that the **merged** manifest will show other third party components that may come from other libraries.  This final manifest is what ends up in your app, and it will look quite different than the one you wrote for yourself.  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#inspect_the_merged_manifest_and_find_conflicts

Comment: There's no android:process attribute in the merged manifest nor our own. Any other way it could become a multi process app?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: In case you're using coroutines or rxjava that might also cause threads to be created in different processes.

Comment: Are the crashes limited to a particular brand of device?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not: https://imgur.com/a/Clz1oRn

Comment: @JudeFernandes how could it create multiple processes? Anything I can do to detect/prevent it?

Comment: How is the firebase database initialized in your app? Similar to https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/15 you might have more luck with wrapping it in a proper singleton (not an unsafe one as shown there) ? ContentProviders do work across processes so this might be the culprit

Comment: @Yrlec If crash occurs in all devices rather than in a specific one, I would say it is a "fortune"  to the developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check in your applicaition class if there is foreign process. Here is an example:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if (!isMainProcess()) {
            // Do not call thread unsafe logic. Just return
            return;
        }
        // Thread unsafe logic.
        ...
    }

    private boolean isMainProcess() {
        int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : manager.getRunningAppProcesses()) {
            String currentProcName = processInfo.processName;
            if (processInfo.pid == pid) {
                if (TextUtils.equals(currentProcName, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are calling the method `setPersistenceEnabled()` multiple times.

Ensure it is not. You can do this in a several ways.
The preferred method will be to place it only in the `onCreate()` method of the default `Application` class if you are extending one.

Another solution will be to place it in the static block of any class.

```
static {
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
}
```

Or you can even set a static boolean variable say, `inFirebaseInstanceInitialized` and call `setPersistenceEnabled()` only if it is not true already.

Comment: We see the same problem with SQLite and H2 dbs. The problem is not that. The problem is that some other db has locked the db file.